# Need help explaining this

Tags: sukkah

Can someone help me understand this Rabbi Akiva Eiger on sukkah 17a? Thank you

https://www.sefaria.org/Chiddushei_Rabbi_Akiva_Eiger_on_Sukkah.17a.2?lang=bi

Comment: Could you explain what you need help with?

Comment: He essentially proves that you need to employ lavud for air gaps less than 3 tefachim. He then asks on Tosafos that regardless of how lavud operates conceptually—either via populating the gap with what is next to it or by closing it by bringing the sides together as if the gap doesn't exist—you're out of business as you'll either have almost 7 tefachim in a row in the first conception (2+>3 air gap+2) of disqualified sechach or 4 tefachim (2+2) in the latter and 4 tefachim of disqualified sechach is problematic . .

Comment: @Nahum ahhhh got it thank you

Comment: These are great questions but, next time, it might be better to copy/translate the text you are having questions in, then explaining what you don't understand with it. Will be more fruitful and easier on answerers than to force them to go look put he text themselves. Will also make it easier to understand the answers in context

Comment: @mbloch will do, thanks